# execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' android studio 1.4.1

Tags: java, android, imageview

I made projects in Eclipse with ADK, but today i have installed Android Studio, created my first project HelloWorld and faced with problem: I added one ImageView, if I set beckgroung (or src) with any system resources - all right, but when I set my box.png file I get errors:
1. execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
2. no resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable)
I tried all the options of the website https://stackoverflow.com/ and others with same problems, but I didn't solve my problem yet.
Please, help me !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/box" />
```

Comment: did you place this drawable folder?

Comment: are you sure about the naming of the image file and if the image file is proper. box.png should have all small caps.

Comment: I think the image was broken, I take a new png file from internet then the project is working, but it displayed incorrectly then I removed it to mipmap folders and all work correctly.